# Eclipse Svn synchronizing Not working?

Tags: eclipse, svn

Problems reported while synchronizing SVNStatusSubscriber. 0 of 1 resources were synchronized.
An error occurred synchronizing /MedxBilingSchedularPro: Error getting status for resource P/MedxBilingSchedularPro org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: Previous operation has not finished; run 'cleanup' if it was interrupted

Error getting status for resource P/MedxBilingSchedularPro org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: Previous operation has not finished; run 'cleanup' if it was interrupted

org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: Previous operation has not finished; run 'cleanup' if it was interrupted

org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: Previous operation has not finished; run 'cleanup' if it was interrupted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the error message. It provides a clear instruction:

> Previous operation has not finished; **run 'cleanup' if it was
>   interrupted**

Therefore, clean up your project's working copy. If you can't or don't know how to do it through Eclipse by some reason, run [`svn cleanup`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.cleanup.html) from the command line.

Read [SVNBook | Sometimes You Just Need to Clean Up](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.tour.cleanup.html).